# fetch_assoc() выдаёт ошибку Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in

Tags: php

Делаем запрос к БД, и перебираем результат.

```
    $result = $mysqli->query( $query );

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
```

Запрос может ничего не вернуть и  `fetch_assoc()`, получив пустое значение, выдаёт ошибку `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in ...`
Соотвественно, я проверяю `$result`, и получаю:

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 6
    [type] => 0
)
```

Мне эта выборка ни о чём не говорит, причём выводятся эти цифры в независимости о того, вернул запрос результаты или нет. Причём, переменная с результатами вызывается в цепочке функций, и через каждую экранирует свой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения в каждой функции разное. Хотя, объект один и отображаться везде должен одинаково. Но суть вопроса в другом, как прочитать в объекте результата запроса, в `$result`, вернул он поля или нет.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы ищете проблему не там. `fetch_assoc` не сгенерирует ошибку при обращении к результату успешно выполненного `select` запроса, даже если запрос вернул 0 строк.

> Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in

Однозначно говорит о том, что в момент ошибки `$result` был типа `boolean`. А метод [`query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) в свою очередь может дать булевого типа результат если:

- запрос был выполнен с ошибкой
- был выполнен запрос не являющийся, цитирую, `SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN`

Следовательно смотрите какой именно запрос вы выполняли, а так же добавьте проверку результата метода `query` на возможные ошибки.

Comment: Всё правильно,  SQL запрос формировался без необходимых значений.